# Using Include that produces no result will close the reader

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF7 beta3.

When executing two queries on my database, if the first query returns no result and has an include, the second query will fail with a System.InvalidOperationException. I am unable to reproduce the issue in MusicStore and unable to figure out what in my code is causing this.

Throws exception:

```
var db = new EmfdsContext();
var user = db.Users.Include(x => x.Logins).FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == "nonExistantUserName");
var role = db.Roles.Where(x => x.Name == "Subscriber").ToList(); //throws
```

Doesn't throw exception:

```
var db = new EmfdsContext();
var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == "nonExistantUserName");
var role = db.Roles.Where(x => x.Name == "Subscriber").ToList(); //doesn't throw
```

Doesn't throw exception:

```
var db = new EmfdsContext();
var user = db.Users.Include(x => x.Logins).FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == "existantUserName");
var role = db.Roles.Where(x => x.Name == "Subscriber").ToList(); //doesn't throw
```

The exception is:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

The logins include doesn't matter, it can be any other relation in the include and it will throw the exception.

Relevant Mappings:

```
builder.Entity<Subscriber>().ForRelational().Table("Subscribers", "ApplicationServices");
builder.Entity<Subscriber>().Key(s => s.Id);
builder.Entity<Subscriber>().HasMany(s => s.SubscriberGroups).WithOne(sg => sg.Subscriber).ForeignKey(sg => sg.Subscriber_Id);
builder.Entity<Subscriber>().HasMany(s => s.Roles).WithOne().ForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);

builder.Entity<Role>().ForRelational().Table("Roles", "ApplicationServices");
builder.Entity<Role>().Key(r => r.Id);
builder.Entity<Role>().HasMany(r => r.Users).WithOne().ForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);
builder.Entity<Role>().HasMany(r => r.MenuRoles).WithOne(mr => mr.Role).ForeignKey(mr => mr.Role_Id);
```

StackTrace:

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Query.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__8`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryExecutor.EnumerableExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at EMFDS.WebApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\nicolas.bourgoin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\emfds_dev2\emfds\src\EMFDS.WebApplication\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 25

**Update 1**

Finally, I can reproduce this issue with MusicStore. However, it only throws an exception when you include a one to many relationship (a collection). If you include a many to one relationship, the exception is not thrown.

Comment: The EF team may take the position that this is beta software, and that they make no guarantees that it works at all.  Have you reported the bug to them?  Have you tried wrapping your code in a `using` statement?

Comment: I understand this is beta. I've been playing with it simply to test and learn.  I haven't reported the bug yet since in the contribution page, it is said they also monitor SO. However, this code works in the MusicStore sample app. As for the using, I have also tried. Same problem

Comment: I forwarded then question to the EF team. You should hear from them soon.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace from the exception message?

Comment: Alternatively, you can try using the latest nightly build of EntityFramework, This could very well be an issue that we have resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back and verified that this is an issue with the beta3 release of EF7, but it has been resolved in the current development branch.

Comment: Any idea on what commit fixed this? I am unable to get the nightly builds to work for some shady reasons.

Comment: Installing EF7 via nuget is a little broken currently. Rather than installing the nuget package, you can reference the EF source directly by checking out the EF repository from GitHub, running build.cmd then adding references in your solution to the csproj files from EF.

Comment: When I reference the csproj files, I do get a lot of "Ambiguous Error" between EntityFramework and EntityFramework.Core. EntityFramework points to Assembly EntityFramework
    C:\Users\nicbo_000.NICK-LAPTOP\.k\packages\EntityFramework\7.0.0-alpha3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll  How can I remove that link to the old file if it's not in use anywhere in any of the projects?

Comment: Your best option at this point might be sticking with the beta3 version and working around the issue (i.e. restructure the query or use a different context if the two calls aren't related).There have been enough breaking changes in the APIs, project structure, and runtime that you would need to use the latest versions for everything, and the currently available version of Visual Studio is not compatible with the updates.